# How do I install this script as root in terminal: ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.3.2.run?

Tags: x11, software-installation, qt

I need to install qt5 on my system and I can only run it as the normal user. When I try to run it as the "super user" I get this error:

```
root ~ # ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.3.2.run 
No protocol specified
qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.3.2.run: cannot connect to X server :0.0
```

I've done:

```
root ~ # export DISPLAY=:0.0
root ~ # echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

Still no luck.

Questions:

Is there a reason why I wouldn't want to install it as root? Doesn't running it as root supposedly install it "system wide"?

How do I run it as root?

EDIT #1

My distribution is Debian Wheezy if it matters.

If I run it with sudo:

```
~$ sudo ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.3.2.run 
No protocol specified
qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.3.2.run: cannot connect to X server :0.0
```

Same error.

EDIT #2

This script is from [here](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2) and is the qt5 installer(Qt is a cross-platform application and UI development framework. Using Qt, you can easily port a GUI application to multiple platforms without rewriting application code from scratch.)

EDIT #3

From what I can gather from the directions on [this](http://ask.xmodulo.com/install-qt5-linux.html) site, the installer should be run as root, they run it with "sudo" in there?

Exerpt from directions:

```
$ chmod +x qt-linux-opensource-5.2.0-x86-offline.run
$ sudo ./qt-linux-opensource-5.2.0-x86-offline.run
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `sudo`? Does it work if you run `xhost +` as your regular user before switching to root?

Comment: @terdon I've edited my question.

Comment: Is there an actual problem? Do you need to run it as root? Remember that we have no idea what this script is (you haven't told us). Whether it is installed system-wide or not is completely dependent on what the script does. Don't run things as root unless necessary.

Comment: @terdon Yes I think I shuld run it as root, as they do on the site which I was following. I edited my post.

Comment: OK, so did you try running `xhost +` as I suggested in my first comment?

Comment: @terdon That worked. If you would make that an answer. Else I can answer it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works as expected out of the box on my system. You don't seem to have your `sudo` configured to allow you to run graphical applications. I haven't encountered this issue in quite a few years but one of these should work:

1. Switch off access control for X

   ```
   xhost +
   sudo ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-1.6.0-5-online.run
   ```

   Then, activate it again with `xhost -`.
2. Export your environment to the `sudo` session.

   ```
   sudo -E ./qt-opensource-linux-x64-1.6.0-5-online.run
   ```

   I'm not sure how relevant this one is but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

No there is normally no reason not to install as root, this is quite common. No "running" as root is not the same as installing as root. You should not run this as root, it is in my experience very seldom that an X client needs to be run as root.

Installing and running are different things. Many items need to be installed as root to get into the directories configured during compilation, but they will be run afterwards as "normal" users.

The installing is the final part of the compilation process. The compilation for many packages can be done as a normal user, e.g. in some subdirectory of your homedirectory. But when it comes to installing, the executable binaries and scripts to `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`, and other files to `/usr/lib` etc., you need the special rights root has to write there.¹

This is what you typical get with

```
tar xvf somepackage.tar
cd somepackage
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Only the last command in that chain needs to be done "as root"²

After installation every user can use those executables, but, among other things, this prevents them from altering the "global" setup.

¹ <sub>There are more reasons to do this as root, e.g. when you need to set some [setuid or setgid bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid)</sub>
² <sub>Often the last commands are chained with && so install is only tried when the make succeeded</sub>